# ComboBox to assign UserID value and User Object to entity

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

I have an db generated entity:

```
public partial class UserMobileDevice
{
    public string DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to hook up a ComboBox that selects a User and updates the UserID and User object on a record.

So this is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboDefaultUser" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Username"
          SelectedValuePath="UserID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding TheEntity.UserID, 
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                  NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                                  Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Which updates the UserID on the local entity just fine, however what about the User object? How do I go about assigning that at the same time?

(Using MVVM as well)

[Addition]

As you can see from the `SelectedValue` binding, my `ViewModel` has the `entity` in a `property` called TheEntity. So there is no UserID{get;set;} `property` actually in the `ViewModel`, which I can also use to also set the User object. So how could I accomplish this?

Comment: You can find a user object from the userid (from db) which got updated and then assign to db result to user object.

Comment: Thanks I realize where it comes from and how to get it. I have a list of the users in my ViewModel. I'll try to explain more above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox` will only set *one* property for you. If you want to set both the `User` property and the `UserId` property, you could bind to a custom property that you define in another partial class definition of the same type and that does this for you:

```
public partial class UserMobileDevice
{
    public User UiUser
    {
        get { return User; }
        set
        {
            User = value;
            if (value != null)
                UserId = value.UserId;
        }
    }
}
```

You then bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to this one:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboDefaultUser" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Username"
          SelectedItem="{Binding TheEntity.UiUser, 
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                  NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

Trying to use auto-generated types exactly "as-is" is seldom very useful.